# Unity get all elements in radius 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using 2D.
I wanna get all Objects on Layer X in a specific radius.

- transform.position -> (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
- viewRadius -> Distance, which the player can see. This is working fine.
- targetMask -> The Layer X. All GameObjects that I want, are on this layer.

```
Collider2D[] targetInViewRadius = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, viewRadius, targetMask);
```

Comment: So? What exactly is not working as expected? This is exactly what I would have suggested ... Do all your target objects have 2D colliders attached?

Comment: Here we go. It didn't had a 2d collider. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the objects you can do

```
foreach (var item in targetInViewRadius)
{
    var objects = item.gameObject;
}
```

Comment: The problem is, that targetInViewRadius is empty. I selected the layer X to be the targetMask. ViewRadius is enough big to see the object.